# Naming Convention for Hashes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I got a html file from a friend with extensive .js and .css In that he used:

```
<a href="#" class="mb-control" data-box="#mb-signout">
```

Now, when converting it to .erb, I wrote:

```
<%= link_to '#', html_options = {class: 'mb-control', data-box:'#mb-signout'} %>
```

But i am getting error in :data-box saying NameError.
How can I solve it?

Comment: haha corrected that..

Comment: Your question is still unresolvable. Add error message and backtrace.

Comment: BTW instead of `html_options = ` you should have `html_options:`.

Comment: link_to '#', html_options: {class: 'mb-control', data-box: '#mb-signout'}........ I used that too but still got the SyntaxError .

Comment: Did you learn anything about Rails before you started to use it? Because your question and comments indicate that you should start learning Rails from scratch and maybe it would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

> But i am getting error in :data-box saying NameError. How can I solve
>   it?

You need to specify a `:data` key inside the html_options Hash:

```
<%= 
  link_to(
        'Click me',  #Link text, e.g. <a href=#">Click me</a>  
         '#',        #value for href attribute
         html_options = {class: 'mb-control', data: {box:'#mb-signout'}} 
  )
%>

--output:--
<a class="mb-control" data-box="#mb-signout" href="#">Click me</a>
```